# How to improve code to toggle states between remote button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the models User, Favorite, Kid and Mom.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :favorites

  def favorited?(mom)
    favorites.where(mom_id: mom.id ).any?
  end
end

class Mom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :favorites
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mom
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mom
end
```

I'm listing a bunch of kids for a user and allowing a user to favorite moms inside of the listings of the kids.

```
class KidsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  index
    @kids = Kid.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end

class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :js, :json, :html

  def create
    @mom = Mom.find(params[:id])
    @favorite = current_user.favorites.build(params[:favorites])
    @favorite.mom_id = @mom.id
    @favorite.save

    if request.xhr?
      head :ok
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @favorite = current_user.favorites.find(params[:id])
    @favorite.destroy
  end
end
```

**kids/index**

```
- @kids.each do |kid|
  - if current_user.favorited?(kid.mom)
    %li
      = link_to({ controller: "favorites", action: "destroy", id: current_user.favorites.find_by(mom_id: kid.mom.id).id }, { method: :delete,  remote: true }, data: { toggle_text: 'Favorite', toggle_href: { controller: 'favorites', action: 'create', id: kid.mom.id }}) do
        %i.fa.fa-star-o.fa-fw
        Unfavorite
  - else
    %li
      = link_to({ controller: 'favorites', action: 'create', id: kid.mom.id }, { method: :post,  remote: true }, data: { toggle_text: 'Unfavorite', toggle_href: { controller: "favorites", action: "destroy", id: current_user.favorites.find_by(mom_id: kid.mom.id) } }) do
        %i.fa.fa-star.fa-fw
        Favorite
```

I can't get this to work correctly and I'm guessing its because of how I have my links setup. Or it could be something else. I don't know the alternative ways to do this so I'm asking for help here. What do I need to change in my code so I can toggle the different states of the links and have it still Unfavorite and Favorite through Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle links then first you need something to target that particular link like this:

```
- @kids.each do |kid|
  %li{id: "kid_link_#{kid.mom.id}"}
    - if current_user.favorited?(kid.mom)
      = render partial: "favorite" 
    - else
      = render partial: "unfavorite"

#_unfavorite.html.erb
= link_to({ controller: "favorites", action: "create"}, method: :delete,  remote: true ) do
  %i.fa.fa-star-o.fa-fw
    Unfavorite

#_favorite.html.erb
= link_to({ controller: 'favorites', action: 'destroy'}, method: :post,  remote: true ) do
  %i.fa.fa-star.fa-fw
    Favorite
```

Now you need to handle ajax request when it hit controller code

```
def create
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:id])
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.build(favorite_params)
  @favorite.mom_id = @mom.id
  @favorite.save
end

def destroy
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:id]) # some logic to find mom so that you could target its link
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.find(params[:id])
  @favorite.destroy
end

private
def favorite_params
  params.require(:favorites).permit(:favorite_form_params)
end

#create.js.erb
$("#kid_link_<%=j @mom.id %>").html("<%=j render partial: "favorite" %>");

#destroy.js.erb
$("#kid_link_<%=j @mom.id %>").html("<%=j render partial: "unfavorite" %>");
```